# Using Max in ORMLITE?

Tags: android, ormlite

I need to use max in ORMLITE to retrieve the latest record in ormlite table
Similar to `select max(MODIFIED)FROM TABLE;`

I want to get a single record that has maximum value for datemodified having where userid is id; for particular userid i want to find record with maximum value for date ie to find the latest entry of particular user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't quite tell but I assume you want to know how to query for some object whose `MODIFIED` field is equal to the max value using [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/).  I'm not sure you can do this in SQL without two queries.  I think you are going to have to do a [raw query](http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries) to get the max and then do another query.

I added `queryRawValue(...)` to [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) in version 4.42 so you can do:

```
long max = fooDao.queryRawValue(
    "select max(modified) from foo where userid = ?", id);
// now perform a second query to get the max row
Foo foo = fooDao.queryBuilder().where().eq("modified", max).queryForFirst();
```

By hand you would do:

```
GenericRawResults<String[]> rawResults =
    fooDao.queryRaw("select max(modified) from foo where userid = ?", id);
// there should be one result
long max = Long.parseLong(rawResults.getResults().get(0)[0]);
// now perform a second query to get the max row
Foo foo = fooDao.queryBuilder().where().eq("modified", max).queryForFirst();
```

Comment: @Rigotti - best to ask why making the editing call to rawResults.getResults() was incorrect here. I agree the original and reverted code is incorrect as results is not defined

Comment: @Rigotti: I don't disagree with the edit and you look like you are right. I merely feel it is better to point it out to the person who answered in a comment first just in case there was some underlying reason behind the use of the existing code. That is what I was told myself in the past when I edited answers. Apologies if that is not suppose to be the case. I was just following, what I thought was the rules on editing answers.

Comment: I've made the change.  Thanks @Rigotti for pointing out the problem.

Comment: @Rigotti: Was my explanation OK for you?

Comment: @Fran Yes, yes. It was very clear for me, I did sound a bit harsh, but I just wanted to know what I could be missing :) Thanks for the concern.